# Creating Model in laravel with correct file permissions

Tags: laravel, file-permissions, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

I am having a hard time trying to figure out the issue.

I am creating a Model using this Artisan command,

```
Artisan::call('make:model',['name' =>'Models\\'.$module.'\\'.$model_name]);
```

For whatever reasons,

1.there is a lock icon in the file

2.owner of the file is `www-data`

3.the permission for the file is 644 but when I create the Model from `CLI` the permission of the file is 757.

Comment: Why are you creating a model in this way and not just using Artisan as intended: via the command line?

Comment: Because I wanted to give it a try, is there anything wrong to create model this way?

Comment: `Artisan::call()` is supposed to run artisan commands that are to be executed to run business logic (like sending emails, updating product values, etc), from the app. But making models is part of the development process, not business logic. Now, this has nothing to do with the file permissions, but you asked if there was anything wrong in calling it this way.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: unless you're doing some kind of boilerplate command that will create model/views/controllers for you I suppose.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco, my master tables I would like to create this way  that is why I am using this.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends who runs the code, in this case web-server runs the code, thus Apache or NGINX is the owner of newly created file (same goes for uploads).

You can change this using

- [umask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work)
- change user/group of web-server

---

Best option is to use artisan as its meant to be used, from command line.